# Traversing a linked list to output each node needs a little more

Tags: java

/I am trying to print out all the items in this inChart linked list, there are 4 items i am trying traverse and print but i only stop at the second node and only outputs the second one

'

```
 public T retrieveAll(TableInterface<City, String> inChart) {
    Node tmp = head;

    while(tmp != null) {

        tmp = tmp.getNext();
    return (T) tmp.getItem();
}
return null;
```

}'

Comment: this code won't run (what is head?). please define all of your variables.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you do in the loop is get the next item.  So `tmp` will initially be the second item.  Then, you do a `return` statement, which breaks out of the loop early, so that's why you don't get any other items.

If you want to print the items, try something like

```
public void printAll() {
    for (Node tmp = head; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.getNext()) {
        System.out.println(tmp.getItem());
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't help still stuck and displays only the first node

Comment: for example this is a full functioning method
public T tableRetrieve(KT searchKey) {
  if(((KeyedItem<KT>)head.getItem()).getKey().equals(searchKey)){
  // head = head.getNext();
   return (T) head.getItem();
  }
  
  Node current = head.getNext();
  Node prev = head;
  while(current!= null){
   
    if(((KeyedItem<KT>)current.getItem()).getKey().equals(searchKey)){
     return (T) current.getItem();
    }
    prev = current;
    current = current.getNext();
   
  }
  return null;
 
  }